# SVG Position text relative to parent <g>

Tags: svg

I need to place text relative to the parent `<g>`.

Currently, I have a path and a text element wrapped in a `<g>`. But all the text coordinates are relative to the outer most `<g>`.

```html
<svg width="1000" height="550">
    <g transform="translate(500,275)" stroke-width="2" stroke="black">
        <g>
            <path d="M1.6838893488276108e-14,-275A275,275 0 0,1 238.15698604072065,137.49999999999994L0,0Z" id="path_0" style="fill: rgb(17, 17, 17);"></path>
            <text transform="translate(100, 100)" class="tooltipText" stroke-width="0" fill="white" style="text-anchor: middle;">text</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="M238.15698604072065,137.49999999999994A275,275 0 0,1 -238.1569860407206,137.50000000000009L0,0Z" id="path_1" style="fill: rgb(34, 34, 34);"></path>
            <text transform="translate(100, 100)" class="tooltipText" stroke-width="0" fill="white" style="text-anchor: middle;">text</text>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="M-238.1569860407206,137.50000000000009A275,275 0 0,1 -5.051668046482832e-14,-275L0,0Z" id="path_2" style="fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></path>
            <text transform="translate(100, 100)" class="tooltipText" stroke-width="0" fill="white" style="text-anchor: middle;">text</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The outermost `<g>` has an offset of (500,275), and the inner `<g>` elements have no offset at all. So all your text elements are being positioned at (100,100) + (0,0) + (500,275). Were you somehow expecting them to be magically positioned in the middle of each path object? (Also, is 14 places of decimals *really* necessary? I would have thought 1 would be sufficient.)

Comment: My assumption was that the text coordinates would be relative to the parent group. This SVG is draw using D3, hence the large number of decimals. This could be rounded.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The parent groups are all located at (500,275).

Comment: Right, I'm still slightly confused. Could you give me an example of how to fix this issue?

Comment: @RobertLongson First time using SVG. I'm confused why the text element coordinates are not relative to the parent group. As squeamishossifrage explained, its to do with the transform on the outermost group. Although, I'm still finding it hard to get my head around how to position the text relative to the parent group.

Comment: The issue is, I don't understand why they are not relative to the parent group. I was asking if someone could give me an example, of how to make the text elements relative to the parent group. @RobertLongson

Comment: Your question is similar to this... Let's say you asked why why your cat wasn't black. The rest of us look at your cat, we all see a black cat. We say we don't understand, you already have a black cat. You say, yes but I want to change my cat so it becomes black. Somehow you need to accept that the premise of your question is incorrect and explain why you think you have a black cat.

Comment: I understand that it must be confusing for you. But never having used SVG I'm still trying to work it out. @squeamishossifrage provided an answer that helped. This is what I was looking for, just some explanation of why its working how it is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's hard to see which part of this you're having trouble with, but I'll explain as best I can.

Your SVG picture is 1000 pixels wide and 550 pixels tall:

```
<svg width="1000" height="550">
```

The top level node inside this SVG is a `<g>` node that moves the origin of the coordinate system from the top left corner to (500,275) (i.e., the middle of the drawing area; Y coordinates increase from top to bottom in SVGs)

```
<g transform="translate(500,275)" ... >
```

All the children of this top-level node will therefore use this transformed coordinate system. You have added additional `<g>` nodes as children of this top-level node, but they don't really do anything in this instance because they contain no attributes:

```
<g>
```

As a result, the `<path>` nodes will still be using the same transformed coordinate system that was set up by the top-level `<g>`. These all produce circular sectors with an apex at (0,0). And since (0,0) corresponds to the middle of the drawing area in this transformed coordinate system, that is where they end up:

```
<path d="M0-275A275 275 0 0 1 238 137.5L0 0Z" style="fill: rgb(17, 17, 17);"></path>
<path d="M238 137.5A275 275 0 0 1-238 137.5L0 0Z" style="fill: rgb(34, 34, 34);"></path>
<path d="M-238 137.5A275 275 0 0 1 0-275L0 0Z" style="fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></path>
```

Your `<text>` nodes are also drawn in this coordinate system, but offset by (100,100) because you added a `transform` attribute to shift them 100 pixels down and 100 pixels to the right:

```
<text transform="translate(100, 100)" ... >text</text>
```

So the end result is that all three of your text nodes are drawn at coordinates of (600,375) relative to the top left corner of the drawing area. If you want the text to appear somewhere else, you'll have specify a different offset. For example:

```
<text transform="translate(120,-80)" ... >text</text>
<text transform="translate(0,160)" ... >text</text>
<text transform="translate(-120,-80)" ... >text</text>
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="550">
  <g transform="translate(500,275)" stroke-width="2" stroke="black">
    <g>
      <path d="M0-275A275 275 0 0 1 238 137.5L0 0Z" style="fill: rgb(17, 17, 17);"></path>
      <text transform="translate(120,-80)" class="tooltipText" stroke-width="0" fill="white" style="text-anchor: middle;">text</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M238 137.5A275 275 0 0 1-238 137.5L0 0Z" style="fill: rgb(34, 34, 34);"></path>
      <text transform="translate(0,160)" class="tooltipText" stroke-width="0" fill="white" style="text-anchor: middle;">text</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M-238 137.5A275 275 0 0 1 0-275L0 0Z" style="fill: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></path>
      <text transform="translate(-120,-80)" class="tooltipText" stroke-width="0" fill="white" style="text-anchor: middle;">text</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```