# How to position an SVG's <text> element relatively to its parent <g> element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on a booking tool and as part of the process, users have to select a desk on the map by clicking on it.

Each desk is in a `<g>` with its own `<title>`, `<path>` and `<text>` elements. It seems every `<text>` aligns to the SVG itself, not to their parent `<g>`. We have like ~200 desks, so positioning every desk number is a bit too much work, plus, the floor map can change from time to time. Did I miss anything?

My example is a simplified version:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 453.16 313.93">
    <defs>
        <style>
        .cls-1 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #231f20;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }
        .cls-2 {
            font-size: 30px;
            text-anchor: middle;
        }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M122.05,61.28H.5V.5H122.05V61.28Z"/>
        <text class="cls-2" x="63" y="34">001</text>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M122.05,145.33H.5v-60.78H122.05v60.78Z"/>
        <text class="cls-2" x="63" y="116">002</text>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M122.05,229.38H.5v-60.78H122.05v60.78Z"/>
        <text class="cls-2" x="63" y="200">003</text>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Everything inside SVG, not only text, is positioned absolutely with reference to "0,0" of parent SVG frame.  You can only nest whole SVG elements inside SVG to constitute new reference frame. Or you can use `translate`.
See https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/mimic-relative-positioning-in-svg/
(Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400986/svg-position-text-relative-to-parent-g )

Comment: You should also consider a HTML/SVG approach e.g main map layout based on html elements - table buttons using svg as image assets (you might also use resusable and stylable `<use>` instances). Even if you can facilitate some positioning with group styles - **you still need to calculate a lot** of values according to currently displayed data since svg doesn't have layout features like auto line-wrapping,  like flex or grid ... not even auto-growing/shrinking containers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a transform attribute (or a CSS transform if you like) to change the g coordinate system. All coordinates of children will use that transformed coordinate system.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 453.16 313.93">
    <defs>
        <style>
        .cls-1 {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #231f20;
            stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        }
        .cls-2 {
            font-size: 30px;
            text-anchor: middle;
        }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M122.05,61.28H.5V.5H122.05V61.28Z"/>
        <text class="cls-2" x="63" y="34">001</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0, 30)">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M122.05,145.33H.5v-60.78H122.05v60.78Z"/>
        <text class="cls-2" x="63" y="116">002</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0, 60)">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M122.05,229.38H.5v-60.78H122.05v60.78Z"/>
        <text class="cls-2" x="63" y="200">003</text>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just use the `<g>` element to move around the boxes. Here you can see that all boxes are the same, except the number and the `transform` attribute. Both `<path>` and `<text>` are placed relative to the `<g>` (an imaginary box that is 120x60). The `<path>` just have the width and height of the box (all `d` attributes have the same value/path!) and the `<text>` is placed in the middle of the box using text-anchor and dominant-baseline.

```html
<svg width="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #231f20;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
      .cls-2 {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-anchor: middle;
        dominant-baseline: middle;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(5 5)">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M 0 0 H 120 V 60 H 0 Z"/>
    <text class="cls-2" x="60" y="30">001</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(5 75)">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M 0 0 H 120 V 60 H 0 Z"/>
    <text class="cls-2" x="60" y="30">002</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(5 145)">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M 0 0 H 120 V 60 H 0 Z"/>
    <text class="cls-2" x="60" y="30">003</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```